# Использовать await как промис для пользовательского действия

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, async-await

Хочу использовать `Task` как промис. Т. е. вызываемая функция создаёт некий `Task`, а вызывающая применяет к нему `await`. Тот таск ничего не делает и просто ждёт, пока кто-то ещё его заресолвит. Примерно как с костылём в следующем коде:

```vb
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
  Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Text = "Click the button to continue"
    Await ClikTheButton()
    Me.Text = "Thanks for clicking"
  End Sub

  Private Function ClikTheButton() As Task
    Dim Sem As New SemaphoreSlim(0, 1)

    Dim Handler As EventHandler = Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                    Sem.Release()
                                    RemoveHandler Button1.Click, Handler
                                  End Sub

    AddHandler Button1.Click, Handler
    Return Sem.WaitAsync()
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: TaskCompletionSource по идее подойдёт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо использовать `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
Task ClickTheButton(CancellationToken token) {
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  var registration = token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled());
  EventHandler handler = (o, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(null);

  button1.Click += handler;
  tcs.Task.ContinueWith(_ => { 
    button1.Click -= handler;
    registration.Dispose();
  }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Вот альтернативный вариант того же кода:

```
async Task ClickTheButton(CancellationToken token) {
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  EventHandler handler = (o, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(null);

  using (token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled())
  try {
    button1.Click += handler;
    await tcs.Task;
  }
  finally {
    button1.Click -= handler;
  }
}
```