# Tasks и Thread - организация пареллельности

Tags: .net, многопоточность, tpl, task

Допустим есть такой примерный поток действий - один поток каждую секунду мониторит данные и если они поступили кидает их в очередь(или куда то еще) предварительно, что то с ними сделав. А другой поток тоже мониторит результаты первого и при поступлении вычитывает и как то их процессит. Потоки не убиваются пока живет сервис. Все запускаются из главного.

Я так понимаю, что `Task(TPL)` для таких делов не совсем подходит, верно? Но на данный момент рекомендуют использовать все же `Task` вместо `Thread`.

И мне вот не понятно что правильней выбрать и как это правильно решить архитектурно.

Comment: В принципе, использовать Task для этого можно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549318/178988. Но на самом деле всё зависит от задачи.

Comment: @Qwerty Попробую немного детализировать. Нам в БД приходят данные. Кто и как кладет нам не важно. Мы периодически выгребаем данные из БД, трансформируем их и кидаем в очередь где их параллельно обрабатывает второй поток отправляя их в другой источник. Потоки не отмирают

Когда еще не было Тасков мы все брали ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ну или как то еще). Я так понимаю что Таски больше подходят для await результата(ов) но ни как для параллельной работы или взаимодействия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для задания мониторинга вполне подходит `Task`. Вы можете, вероятно, даже не выделять под него отдельный поток.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var monitoringTask = Monitoring(cts.Token);
// ... дожидаемся конца
cts.Cancel();
await monitoringTask;
```

```
async Task Monitoring(CancellationToken ct)
{
    TimeSpan pollingPause = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    try
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(pollingPause, ct);
            // проверить изменения данных и отправить результат
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }
}
```

А вот для обмена данными между заданиями вам нужна какая-нибудь реализация producer/consumer. Например, [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/10105) описывается вариант с `BlockingCollection<T>` или (если хотите async-интерфейс) `BufferBlock<T>`.

```
async Task Monitoring(CancellationToken ct, BufferBlock<Data> channel)
{
    TimeSpan pollingPause = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    try
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(pollingPause, ct);
            var data = await Task.Run(() => CheckNewData(ct), ct);
            if (data == null)
                continue;
            await channel.SendAsync(data, ct);
        }            
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        channel.Complete();
    }
}
```

---

Ещё подошло бы решение с Reactive Extensions, которые как раз и представляют собой push-поток данных. Но у них достаточно высокий порог входа, так что я бы не рассматривал их для первой версии архитектуры.

Comment: Вы наиболее близки к тому что меня интересует. Я пока немного не до конца понимаю философию Тасков. Немного по другому представлял этот. Вот как то так(псевдокод)

Task.Run(() => GetAndCheckDataAndSendToQueue());
Task.Run(() => GetQueueDataAndSend());

Но это как то ближе к философии Thread-ов, как считаете ?

На данный момент с многопоточностью на ТЫ, простите если что то не понятно описал)

Comment: @Alex: Идея тасков как бы в том, что вы выделяете логическое _задание_ (мониторинг) в отдельный таск. В этом случае вы можете общаться с ним как с целым: дождаться его, скомбинировать несколько их в _большее_ задание, отменить его, передать его куда-то ещё и т. д. А вот то, в каком именно потоке оно бежит — это вопрос второстепенный, технический и решаемый по ходу.

Comment: @Alex: То есть запустить можно и `GetAndCheckDataAndSendToQueue` через `Task.Run`, это по большому счёту всё равно. Но если можно сэкономить поток, обычно так и делают. Хотя для долгоиграющих заданий поток можно не экономить, т. к. это всё равно «разовое» действие.