# Как "схлопнуть" вызовы, чтобы вызываемый код не "захлебнулся"?

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Может есть какой-то готовый код, чтобы не изобретать велосипеды.

Сценарий такой. В коде генерируются некие обновления, которые затем обрабатываются неким методом. Обновления могут генерироваться слишком часто, плюс метод обработки может тормозить, в результате обновления не успевают обрабатываться, накапливаются, обработчик потом делает лишнюю работу. Хотелось бы как-то "накопить" обновления, пока обработчик занят. Причём, сами данные для обновления уже "накапливаются", об этом заботиться не нужно, нужно только разрулить "накопление" запросов к обработчику, чтобы когда обработчик освободиться обрабатывать не все накопившиеся запросы на обновление по отдельности, а за один раз сразу весь пакет "обновлений" обработать.

Как сейчас:

```cs
async Task UpdateFoo()
{
    ...
    await SaveAsync();
}

async Task UpdateBar()
{
    ...
    await SaveAsync();
}

async Task UpdateBaz()
{
    ...
    await SaveAsync();
}

async Task SaveAsync()
{
    // здесь нужно сделать так, 
    // чтобы одновременно обрабатывался только один запрос
    // по окончании которого проверялось бы не было ли ещё запросов
    // и если были, то обновление запускалось бы ещё один раз (сразу за всё "накопленное")
    // и так пока есть обновления по окончании очередной обработки
}
```

Наверняка логика должна быть какая-то простая довольно, и сценарий довольно типовой, но не соображу, как нормально написать. Для того, чтобы зайти один раз - понятно, `SemaphoreSlim`, видимо (с `WaitAsync`). А вот остальное как лучше сделать?

Comment: Producer/consumer? Но его обычно в многопоточном варианте рассматривают...

Comment: Вообще, а можно ли их пачкой выполнять? Что если одно из изменений в середине некорректное?

Comment: @Qwertiy В какой-то степени да, продюсер-консбюмер, но не хочется на консьюмер специально отдельный поток крутить всё время и хочется как-то "схлопывать" много запросов в одну обработку.

Comment: @Qwertiy Состояние данных всегда корректное, в очереди стоят только запросы на обработку этих данных. Суть в том, чтобы эти запросы выполнялись как один единственный запрос. Фактически это как флаг взвести. Десять запросов - всё-равно один флаг.

Comment: Думаю, стоит выбрать наиболее полезный ответ и отметить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общий пример, берём `System.Threading.Channels.Channel<T>`.

```
private readonly Channel<T> _channel = Channel<T>.CreateUnbounded();
```

Пишем метод разрегребания

```
private Task _workerTask;

private async Task WorkerAsync()
{
    ChannelReader<T> reader = _channel.Reader;
    List<T> list = new();

    // ждём здесь, если в канале пусто
    while (await reader.WaitToReadAsync())
    {
        // забираем всё что есть
        // ну или можно счётчиком ограничить максимальное количество выгребаемых данных за раз
        while (reader.TryRead(out T data))
        {
            list.Add(data);
        }
        // пачка собрана, погнали. это можно в try-catch завернуть, чтобы воркер не падал
        await UseAsync(list);
        list.Clear();
    }
}
```

Стартуем воркер

```
_workerTask = WorkerAsync();
```

Чтобы закинуть в канал

```
_channel.Writer.TryWrite(x);
```

Чтобы закрыть канал (насовсем), и чтобы метод `WorkerAsync` завершился, нужно вызвать

```
_channel.Writer.Complete();
await _workerTask;
```

Вот и вся магия.

---

Вот код на основании вашего самоответа, с точно такой же логикой

```
private readonly Channel<T> _channel = Channel<T>.CreateBounded(1); // максимум один в очереди

private async Task WorkerAsync()
{
    await foreach (var data in _channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            await _producer.SendAsync(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "Ошибка отсылки обновлений");
        }
    } 
}

/// <summary>
/// Отсылка с ограничениями: один поток отсылает, ещё один может ждать в очереди, остальные просто возвращаются
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private void SendUpdatedData()
{
    if (!channel.Writer.TryWrite(GetData())
    {
        _logger.Debug("Уже есть ожидание отсылки обновления...");
    }
}
```

Здесь только консьюмера запустить один раз на всё вермя работы приложения, а как его остановить, показано выше - `_channel.Writer.Complete()`

```
Task task = WorkerAsync(); // ну или `_ = ...`
```

Смысл этого таска для того что если у вас приложения завершается, вы например можете вызвать `Complete()` и через `await task;` дождаться когда все запросы воркером обработаются, после чего нормально завершить работу. А в предложенном вами решении такой возможности не предусмотрено.

Comment: Погоди, а тот, кто делал `await SaveAsync()` как узнает, что именно его сохранение выполнено? А то что-то код выгладит в стиле fire and forget без расчёта на await.

Comment: @Qwertiy здесь написано `UseAsync`, но это собственно оно. А так, если надо подождать выполнения или вернуть ответ, внутрь `T` можно напихать чего угодно. Здесь нет ни одного fire-and-forget. Все таски авэйтятся.

Comment: У него в вопросе код: `async Task UpdateFoo() { ... await SaveAsync(); }` - я полагаю, что `SaveAsync` должно завершиться после того, как сохранятся изменения, существующие на момент его вызова. Насколько я понимаю, в твоём коде оно сделает `_channel.Writer.TryWrite(x);` - а как оно узнает, что его задача попала в некую пачку, которая была выполнена? `await UseAsync(list);` есть, но он сам по себе и гарантирует отсутствие одновременно выполняемых сохранений, но кажется, `SaveAsync` вообще о нём не в курсе.

Comment: @Qwertiy верно, здесь забота об успехах и ошибках ложится на воркера. Вызывающий код может просто недумая и ничего не ожидая накидывать работы в канал сколько влезет, а воркер обработает. Ещё раз. Если надо на единицу работы вернуть обратную связь, это может быть реализовано внутри `T`, это не проблема в целом, десяток строк кода, но может это и не нужно. Подождём фидбэка автора вопроса.

Comment: А, типа этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549318/178988 поместить внутрь типа T и вернуть такую таску из SaveAsync? Плюсанул.

Comment: @Qwertiy вариантов куча. Если нужна колбэковая таска, можно и `TaskCompletionSource` использовать. Но опять же, если есть потребность.

Comment: О, насчёт каналов отличная идея, всё никак руки не доходили, надо разобраться. Единственно что, я вот не хотел под это воркер делать, думал запускать процесс когда пришли запросы, а потом прекращать, но наверное никуда не деться. Вопрос - а не нужно это как long running task оформлять, или в современном .NET это больше не актуально?

Comment: @CrazyElf ну создайте канал, запустите воркер, закройте канал когда вам надо. Воркер асинхронный, он не занимает потоков. Когда нет данных, он просто сидит и ждёт асинхронно, когда вы что-то добавите в канал. О каких тасках речь? Это не синхронный код. В каналах там даже изучать особо нечего, это обычный Producer/Consumer примитив. А если не воркер, то надо все равно очередь где-то хранить. Канал это и есть то самое хранилище, при чём потокобезопасное.

Comment: Спасибо за добавление, почитаю, осознаю.

Comment: Не понял, а кто последнее изменение сохранять будет, если оно произойдёт в момент сохранения?

Answer (score 2):

Если все вызовы SaveAsync идут из одного потока, то можно реализовать так:

1. Помещаем в очередь изменение
2. Если работа по сохранению уже в процессе, ждём её завершения
3. Если очередь не пуста

   4. забираем всё из неё
   5. свою задачу сохраняем как ожидающую завершения

   Иначе

   4. ждём завершения сохранения

Если вызовы могут быть многопоточными, то надо офигенно аккуратно расставить локи так, чтобы они покрывали все дайствия, но не время ожидания.

---

Что-то такое (но ничего не гарантирую, и вообще, писал прямо тут):

```
object lobj = new();
List<...> changes = new();
Task active = Task.FromResult();

async Task SaveAsync()
{
  Task cur;

  lock (lobj)
  {
    changes.Add(...);
    cur = active;
  }

  await cur;

  lock (lobj)
  {
    if (changes.Count !== 0)
    {
      active = cur = SaveAsyncReal(changes.ToList());
      changes.Clear();
    }
    else
      cur = active;
  }

  await cur;
}

async Task SaveAsyncReal(List<...> diff)
{
  ...
}
```

Но если сюда ещё и обработку ошибок надо присобачить, то это вообще долго думать надо...

Comment: У автора асинхронный код, какие локи? :)

Comment: @aepot, во-первых, а в чём противоречие? Во-вторых, примерно накидал.

Comment: В принципе код норм, в стиле JS, где нет всяких `Channel<T>`.

Comment: @aepot, зато не требует лишнего потока)

Comment: Я бы в начале заyieldил `Task`, а локи бы шевелил потом. Но многое зависит от контекста синхронизации. Потоки могут как меняться, так и нет после await, в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: @aepot, в каком смысле заелдил? У меня нет итераторов. Или имеется в виду заэвейтил? А откуда их взять до лока? Вроде мой вариант не зависит от потоков?

Comment: Когда планируется задержка в синхронной части метода, лучше выплюнуть таск в вызывающий авейт сразу `await Task.Yield();` первой строкой метода.

Comment: Я же вроде намекнул, что можно использовать semaphoreSlim, он вместо лока для асинхронного кода используется ) В целом спасибо за идею, надо подумать осознать. А, ещё тут цикла нет, разгребающего накопившееся, пока шла отработка, вопрос во многом в этом цикле.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну да, семафор может быть эффективнее. Про цикл не понял: SaveAsyncReal принимает список изменений и должна их пачкой сохранить.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, но пока изменения обрабатываются может ещё пачка прийти и их тоже надо обработать. Может логика с локами это и делает, но как-то я не очень осознал что тут происходит. И локи с асинком лучше не мешать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, должна сделать. Если я нигде не накосячил.

Answer (score 0):

Сам пока сделал на таске и двух семафорах, хотя другие решения тоже интересные, но не совсем подходят под мою задачу.
Суть в том, что одно обновление работает, другое ожидает в очереди, все остальные обновления отбрасываются - они излишни, второго ожидающего обновления достаточно.

```cs
private void SendUpdatedData()
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () => { await SendAsync(); });
}

/// <summary>
/// Отсылка с ограничениями: один поток отсылает, ещё один может ждать в очереди, остальные просто возвращаются
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task SendAsync()
{ 
    if (_semaphore2.CurrentCount == 0)
    {
        _logger.Debug("Уже есть ожидание отсылки обновления...");
        return;
    }
    await _semaphore2.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await _semaphore1.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            var data = GetData();
            await _producer.SendAsync(data);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore1.Release();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "Ошибка отсылки обновлений");
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore2.Release();
    }
}
```

Покритикуйте, пожалуйста. )

Comment: ` _ = Task.Run(async () => { await SendAsync(); });` так нельзя, но если очень хочется, то это делается так `_ = Task.Run(() => SendAsync());` не надо здесь никаких async-await. Манипуляций с семафорами не понял. Также не понял, чем вам каналы не угодили. Если там нужно сделать отлуп вызывающему коду, если очередь переполнена, есть Bounded канал. `Channel.CreateBounded<T>(2)`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо. А почему именно так нельзя? У меня там try/catch ещё на самом деле, поэтому await внтури try/catch. Насчёт CreateBounded почитаю, спасибо! C семафорами я делаю то, что описал - один запрос обрабатывается, второй ждёт в очереди, остальным отлуп.

Comment: Потому что это эквивалент `async void`. Разница только в принудительном запуске на пуле потоков и без того асинхронного кода.

Comment: @aepot, `Task.Run(SendAsync)` - не? Зачем лямбда?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно и так

Comment: Не уверен, что к `CurrentCount` можно так обращаться. Да и вообще сомнительно выглядит.

Comment: @Qwertiy Собственно лямбда у меня нужна была, чтобы можно было `async` и `await` написать, если `async` не нужен, то и лямбда не нужна, ага.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну так то вообще-то работает, но это не окончательное решение. А насчёт `CurrentCount` - а зачем вообще это свойство иначе нужно, как его ещё использовать? )  Я где-то именно такой пример подсмотрел.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а если он изменится?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не понял вопроса. Про потокобезопасность если, то вроде везде без локов его используют.