Управление сервисом, работающим на UdpClient, используя api контроллеры C#
У меня возникла необходимость отправлять запросы на сервер, работающий по udp, и получать ответы в том месте, где посылаю запросы. Проблема в том, что на некоторое запросы приходят несколько ответов, причем в разное время (например, при посылке запроса на получения разрешения слать данные сначала приходит разрешение на посылку, а потом через некоторое время приходит запрет, если не слать данные несколько секунд). Я попытался реализовать асинхронный прием сообщений и обрабатывать их в EventHandler, но после переюроса ответственности на обработчик вернуть пользователю пришедшие данные никак не выйдет без костылей.
private async void ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var receivedResult = await _client.ReceiveAsync(token);
            Notify?.Invoke(receivedResult.Buffer);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);        
    }
}

А вот тот самый обработчик, который находится в другом классе:
private void ResponseHandler(byte[] bytes)
{
    var parsedData = _parseService.ParseStructure(bytes);

    if (parsedData.Item2 == null)
        return;

    switch (parsedData.Item1)
    {
        case ResponseType.Registartion:
            var registrationResponse = _responseFabric.CreateRegistrationResponse(parsedData.Item2);
            _logger.Log(registrationResponse.ToString());
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

Как мне быть в моей ситуации?

Читайте из сокета в фоновом обработчике, и распределяйте ответы при помощи решений из вот этих ответов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/793724/178779, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549318/178779
